# Use mock frameworks for something else then unit-tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking

Do mock frameworks are just supporting to write unit tests or are there any other cases where a developer would use them?

Are there situations where they are useful outside the testing area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of mock objects is that they're "not real" objects. At least "not real" in the sense they're "not production" objects. That's pretty much by definition, making the short answer to your question: no.

However, that said: you could very easily find yourself with a mock object that you later discover has a functional purpose in production code.

A simple example would be if you wrote a mock object to implement a particular interface, but all methods implementing the interface do nothing. This is also known as a *null implementation* object.
Null implementation objects do serve a useful purpose in production code, and you could one day decide to use that implementation in your production code. Although when you do so, you should no longer consider that object to be a *mock* object. You would define the null implementation object in production code, and change your test cases to rather use the null implementation object.

For a practical example:

- If some of your code under test calls a logger, you generally don't want your test cases to bother with first setting up a temporary log file which will also have to be deleted.
- So your test cases might define a mock logger that is a null implementation object, and ensure logging within the testing framework uses that instead.
- Later you might decide to add a feature to your application to disable logging.
- You don't want to write `if assigned(Logger) then Logger.write(...)` each time the logger is called.
- So instead, your application will set `Logger` to a null implementation object whenever logging is disabled.

Comment: That's a good point, I specifically experienced the Logger-example at work a few years ago and that would have been a good solution

Comment: @MOnsDar But that's not a mock, it's an implementation that doesn't do anything. In testing you'd mock to ensure compliance to your expectations, in your real code, no mock.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to extend/change class behavior outside the test environment you'd extend/modify/subclass the class in question.

Mocking occurs in source code, just like sub-classing does, so no benefit there. Mocks don't persist outside the runtime environment, so they're not a deployable artifact. Mocks don't include behavior other than what is explicitly defined.

There *might* be a legitimate use for them outside of testing, but I'm having trouble finding one that wouldn't be better served by AOP.